# Primary key in sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite, database-design

I'm designing a new Python application to store historical and realtime stock trades using Sqlite3.  
The database will store many stock symbols with varying amount of data.  
Some symbols would have data for every day, some would only have the current day.
  
  
My problem is to decide on the best database design in terms of disk efficiency and speed performance.  
One approach is to use one table per symbol and the PK would be datetime (text or integer).  It makes sense since my analyser will only need a few tables at a time. Con: the database will contain many thousands of tables.
  
The other approach would be to use one table for all stocks. The PK would be a compound of 2 columns (Stock+datetime).
  
  
 Best design decision requires a good knowledge about cache management in sqlite3.
  
  
Which approach would be the best?
  
Is there a tool to simulate or estimate performance?
  
What would be your choice? based on what?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend having a unique table to store the trades instead of multiple tables.

From database normalization perspective, all data of the same entity should be store in the same table (obviously, a stock trade is an entity). If you spread your data into multiple tables, querying across trades will be tedious, and require hardcoding table names, or using dynamic SQL.

You mentionned 0 to 1 row per trade and per day, so unless you have a huge number of quotes, the volume of the table should be reasonable.

I would also recommend having a separate table to store the list of stocks, with an auto-incremented primary key (and possibly a unique key on the stock name); the daily trades table should then reference that table through a forein key constraint. This allows you to guarantee referential integrity, while also limiting the size of trades table (an integer is usually cheaper than a string).

Comment: Thanks @GMG. My post was not explicit enough. I will use DynamicSQL so I won't need hardcoding tableName. And the database will contain trades at a 1 second resolution (around 25000 per day) for stocks that my analyser will study (only a few stocks per day). Does this change your answer?

Comment: @user3435121: that's an option, but still adds a lot of complexity, which in my opinion is not needed for your use ase.

Comment: I vote for a single table. Managing thousands of tables will become a nightmare.